# jQuery fullCalendar eventSource

Tags: events, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery FullCalendar, version 1.5, with its Month View option. My task is to populate the events from xml type data that is stored in client database. I have used the sample and it worked fine. 
Now can anyone tell me how to create an array of events and assign it to events of the calendar? 
Its urgent and i have to deliver it as soon as possible.

Comment: In whatever your language is (e.g. PHP) you need to retrieve the data from your data store (e.g. MySQL, XML file) and put that in an array, then encode the array as JSON for fullcalendar to consume. If you show some code, we can help you do this.